# Magento Product REST API for configurable and grouped products

Tags: product, configurable-product, api, grouped-products, rest-api

I can not find the REST API documentation for creating a configurable product over the REST API from Magento

I also can not find the documentation for relating simple products with a product over REST.

Comment: Is this not it? http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html `HTTP Method: POST /products` and `type_id`

Comment: Second thought... maybe it's not possible.

Comment: @TimHallman We need to associate the child products with the parent. that is the part I am looking for

Comment: Considering this job posting, I'm assuming it's not an 'out of the box' option, but I could be wrong https://www.upwork.com/o/jobs/job/_~0103376d277453e2df/. Definitely interested in what you find out.

Answer (score 1):

None of this exists for the RESTful API. We created all this functionality as well as the relation of products and CRUD for categories. (They exist as SOAP now)